# How to Unittest autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView (Django autocomplete light)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm Using the Django package `Django Auto Complete light` and here is how I use it:

in the **urls.py** I use :

```py
    path('buy-invoice-items-autocomplete/', views.ItemAutoComplete.as_view(), name='buy_invoice_items_autocomplete', ),
```

then in the **views.py** :

```py
class ItemAutoComplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Item.objects.filter().order_by('id')
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(id__iexact=self.q) | Q(name__icontains=self.q))
        return qs
```

And finally i use it in my **forms.py** to let the user filter using it.

Now when I try to include it in my unit tests file I do it this way :

```py
class TestItemAutoComplete(TestCase):
    def test_visit(self):
        self.client.get('/buy-invoice-items-autocomplete/')
```

Using **Coverage** package it shows that my test is not covering the lines:

```py
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(id__iexact=self.q) | Q(name__icontains=self.q))
```

How to reach this part in the class and test it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the autocomplete text (query parameter `q`) in your test calls, for example:

```
class TestItemAutoComplete(TestCase):
    def test_visit(self):
        self.client.get('/buy-invoice-items-autocomplete/?q=foo')
        self.client.get('/buy-invoice-items-autocomplete/?q=bar')
```

Otherwise `q` will be empty so `if self.q` is false and the following line will not be called during the test.